# Windows Phone LongListSelector first visible row

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm new to windows Phone and this is my first post.

I was wondering if it is possible while scrolling through the list to know the top visible row at any given moment during the scrolling because the top visible row will always change as long as the user keeps scrolling.

Thanks in advance

Seems a similar question is already asked

[Save scroll position of LongListSelector control in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226370/save-scroll-position-of-longlistselector-control-in-windows-phone-8)

Comment: @Lizz, Hi, the LongListSelector is bound to a viewmodel, that's all. For this particular problem, I have no code so far, since I have no clue how to get the top visible item. Thx

Answer (score 0):

[Please check this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/44a17ea7-e807-43b3-973f-e2cff4a48630/get-the-first-and-last-visible-element-of-widows-phone-listbox?forum=wpdevelop)

you will get index of top visible item,if its not visible completely then you can use this to view it completely:

```
lstbx.ScrollTo(index)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, trying to implement the example from the link, but a LongListSelector doesn't have a ContainerFromIndex method. Thx

Comment: Great! you just wanted to find solution to get list item ,ie VisualTreeHelper instead of ListBox's Container APIs

Comment: the link was not correct. This is the correct one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121139/how-can-i-get-the-verticaloffset-of-a-longlistselector-in-wp8/15130995#15130995